# Trying to get property of non-object in PHP Laravel Application

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following Query that returns an array

```
    $wines = Wine::all();

    //Remove type_id and producer_id
    foreach ($wines as $wine) {
        $location = $wine->producer->location;
    }
```

This is what I get if i echo $wine->producer->location;

```
{"city": "Kavadartsi", "address": "29-ти Ноември, бр. 5, Kavadartsi 1430", "country": "Macedonia"}
```

So the only property that I need from this is the address which I try to access with

```
$wine->producer->location->address;
```

But when I do so I get the following error

```
Trying to get property 'address' of non-object
```

If I change the code to

```
$wine->producer->location['address'];
```

The error is:

```
Illegal string offset 'address'
```

Comment: Remove the arrow after `location`: `$wine->producer->location['address'];`

Comment: @PrinceDorcis Sorry my bad, I already have ti as $wine->producer->location['address']; And I get that error

Comment: Is `$wine->producer->location` really an object or is it a Json string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of this is wrong: `$wine->producer->location->['address'];`, you might want to do this instead `$wine->producer->location['address'];`.

If that doesn't work, then it would help a lot to see what your producer migration file looks like, but if am to guess it is probably in json like `$table->json('location');`.
If this is the case then you may want to type cast that particular field like this:

```
<?php

class Location extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'location' => 'array',
    ];
}
```

After you've done this you can now get your data like this:

```
$wine->producer->location['address'];
```

Comment: That is exactly what the migration was like, and this solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the arrow after location: $wine->producer->location['address'];

If you are getting the same error and if location is in JSON format in your database, json_decode it:

```
$location = json_decode($wine->producer->location, true);
$address = $location['address'];
```